# Erlang add element to same list

Tags: list, erlang, element

Erlang add element to same list? is it possible in erlang? If not then Please help me someone to achieve this with any alternate solution.

Actual requirement which I have to do is as follows:

I have multiple list ids so based on list ids, I have to fetch all subscribers email id whose status is not equal to 'B', 'U' (Bounced and Unsubscribed) into 1 list and after that I have to remove duplicate email ids from that listSubscribers, once I got the proper ListSubscriber then I'll loop it and send email to all unique subscribers. Issue comes here when loop it to list to fetch all subscribers first time when I get subscribers
and when loop goes to second one and gets the subscribers and it will add to the same list throwing error bcoz list is already bound.

Sample Code what I am doing...

```
% I have multiple list it can be any number, So by loop through each list id fetching subscribers.

lists:foreach( fun (ListId) -> 

ListSubscribers = emailmarketing:get_list_subscribers(ListId), %% Here I am fetching All email subscriber Ids...

io:fwrite("Total Subscriber from this list -> ~p ~n", [ListSubscribers])

end, ListIds),

UniqueSubscriberList = lists:usort(ListSubscribers),

%% Now I'll loop here and send each subscriber campaign email.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just like what @sch said and what was posted in your previous question, you'll have to create a new variable and assign the return value of `lists::append()` into that new variable.

Comment: Ajay,  programming in a functional language is very different than programming in an imperative languages like Java, Python, JavaScript, etc.  In Erlang, data structures are immutable, variables can only be bound once, there are no built in loop constructs.  It is a very different language than those you may be used to.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Erlang is a functional programming language. It's very different from imperative languages like C or PHP. Coding Erlang *will* require basic understanding of functional programming, including single assignment, recursion, higher-order functions and also possibly list comprehensions.

List comprehensions can be really useful in your scenario. I think much of what you're trying to do can be written like this:

```
ListSubscribers = lists:flatten([emailmarketing:get_list_subscribers(ListId) || ListId <- ListIds])
```

Comment: Hey Emil, Thanks for your suggestion, I am begineer to erlang...so unable to get it properly what u have given above... What does this... what is happening in this...please explain if possible...

Comment: What is the return type of emailmarketing:get_list_subscribers/1 and what do you want ListSubscribers to look like?

Comment: No, I won't explain my code further since it is so simple. Please consult the Erlang documentation or a book on the subject (I use *Erlang Programming* from O'Reilly). Read about list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

Erlang is single assigment functional language. All you have to do is assign to one var first list and to var to second next concat the list and this will get you ListThree with results.
So you always produce new list while "changing" (adding, removing, updating, etc).

```
ListOne = getSubs1(),
ListTwo = getSubs2(),
ListThree = lists:append(ListOne, ListTwo),
```

next when you apply filter removing unwanted you produce another list,

```
ListFour = lists:filter(fun(X) -> ... end, ListThree).
```

etc. You always produce new list every time you change something never change previous one.

In your case `ListSubscribers` is visible only in scope of forall fun you should change it to something like map and your `map` or `filter` will produce result list like this.

```
ListOfLists = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
ResultList = lists:filter(fun(X) X rem 2 =:= 0 -> end, ListOfLists),
```

so ResultList will be all elements that returns true from our fun.

```
[2,4,6]
```

And next you will have to apply next filters on it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution I have used recursive method to combine my list with new element. Here is the example:

```
combine_list_subscriber([First | Rest]) ->
    {Subscriber} = bson:lookup ('subscriber', First),
    [Subscriber | combine_list_subscriber(Rest)];
combine_list_subscriber([]) ->
    [].
```

Thanks,
Ajay